# typescript version error after updating angular cli

Tags: angular, typescript

After upgrading to latest stable angular cli I start getting typescript error. I tried installing all latest compatible version but no luck.

The issue is ng new command is broken & npm install also give error for this application. not sure what went wrong & how to fix.

Any guidance will be really appreciated.

[image: all installed version]

[image: nvm list]

[image: Error part]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

1. `npm uninstall -g @angular/cli`
2. `npm cache verify`
3. `npm cache clear --force`
4. `npm install -g @angular/cli@latest`

Or manually update your global files. For windows you can find package.json.template here: (I don't know by heart where to find them on linux or mac.)

C:\Users<USER_NAME>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@angular\cli\node_modules@schematics\angular\workspace\files

My ts version:

```json
"typescript": "~4.3.2"
```